# File upload control in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

How top upload a file in wp8.I could  not find upload control.Is it possible to upload a document and can it open hard disk memory(where document resides)

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [File upload control in windows phone8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24489144/file-upload-control-in-windows-phone8)

Answer (score 0):

In windows phone 8, There is no control like `FileUpload` instead of that you need to use Background Agent to upload files. here are two Good Samples you can go through [How to Upload a File from a Windows Phone App](http://blog.anthonybaker.me/2013/06/how-to-upload-file-from-windows-phone.html) and [Auto-upload Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Auto-upload-Sample-0afb5b95)