# File upload control in windows phone8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, file-upload

I cannot find any control to upload files in windows phone .Is it possible to upload files in wp 8.When we click it  must open phone memory(where the document resides)

Comment: I didn't get you completely.. You want to upload(open) file from Phone Memory...?

Comment: something what we do it for gmail attach document(upload document) that we have to choose it from phone memory

Comment: As Pradeep AJ's answer suggested you can't access other files rather than Images from phone memory. Apart from this you can access Isolated storage which is specied some of memory to you application [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463165/read-from-internal-storage-in-windows-phone-8?answertab=votes#tab-top ].

Answer (score 1):

In windows phone 8, There is no control like `FileUpload` instead of that you need to use `Background Agent` to upload files. here are two Good Samples you can go through [How to Upload a File from a Windows Phone App](http://blog.anthonybaker.me/2013/06/how-to-upload-file-from-windows-phone.html) and [Auto-upload Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Auto-upload-Sample-0afb5b95)

Comment: I think we can upload images using phone chooser task but i need to upload doc format files

Answer (score 0):

If  you are going to Upload Image files, then you can use the PhotoChooserTask  to select file and upload file using the [HttpClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/2.2.18) Library.

For other file types, You can access ONLY if it is stored in SD card. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj720573%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for accessing files from SD Card in windows phone.

Only in Windows Phone 8.1, you can access the Downloads Folder.